# How to create .tbz files

Tags: linux

I have a folder with plenty of files and I have to create .tbz archive files for each.

For examples if I have 2000 files in a folder, I would want to create .tbz for each of those 2000 files. What command will work here?

Comment: `tbz` implies a bzip-compressed tar file; do you really need one tar archive per file, or could you simply compress each file?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: I'm also curious as to why you need 2000 archives. Wouldn't it make more sense to just compress all of them using `tar -cvfj folder.tbz folder`?

Comment: I was just curious how to do it. It's not a school assignment or anything. I am just playing around with random test cases which I am creating. Just seeing how things work etc.